# Firefox: set delay for certain events in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am capturing video on website loading. I noticed that Firefox sends http requests even before the GUI is completely loaded, so sometimes there are gray/white screens at the beginning. My question is that how to set delay on any events(http request events in my case) in firefox or by extensions?